# Query parameters in Express

Tags: node.js, express, query-string

I am trying to get access to query parameters using Express in Node.js.  For some reason, `req.params` keeps coming up as an empty object.  Here is my code in `server.js`:

```
const express    = require('express');
const exphbs     = require('express-handlebars');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const https      = require('https');

//custom packages  ..
//const config  = require('./config');
const routes  = require('./routes/routes');


const port = process.env.port || 3000;


var app = express();

//templating engine Handlebars
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');





//connect public route
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));


app.use(bodyParser.json());

//connect routes
app.use('/', routes);






app.listen(port,  () => {
    console.log( 'Server is up and running on ' + port );
});
```

And here is my routes file:

```
//updated
const routes = require('express').Router();


routes.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('home');
});



routes.post('/scan',  (req, res) => {
    res.status(200);

    res.send("hello");
});



routes.get('/scanned',  (req, res) => {

    const orderID = req.params;
    console.log( req );

    res.render('home', {
        orderID
    });
});

module.exports = routes;
```

When the server is up and running, I am navigating to `http://localhost:3000/scanned?orderid=234`.  The console log that I currently have in the `routes.js` file is showing an empty body (not recognizing `orderid` parameter in the URL).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`orderid` in the request is query parameter. It needs to be accessed via `req.query` object not with `req.params`. Use below code to access `orderid` passed in the request:

```
const orderID = req.query.orderid
```

Now you should be able to get `234` value passed in the request url.

Or try replacing the code for route `/scanned` with below:

```
routes.get('/scanned',  (req, res) => {

  const orderID = req.query.orderid
  console.log( orderID ); // Outputs 234 for the sample request shared in question.

  res.render('home', {
    orderID
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that `req.body` keeps coming up as an empty object is that in `get` requests, such as those made by the browser on navigation, there is no body object. In a `get` request, the query string contains the orderid that you are trying to access. The query string is appended to the url. Your code can be rewritten as below:

```
routes.get('/scanned',  (req, res) => {

    const orderID = req.query.orderid
    console.log( req );

    res.render('home', {
        orderID
    });
});
```

A note, though, is that if you have AJAX posts firing within your client side code, your `req.body` will not be empty, and you can parse it as you would normally.