# How can I parse parameters to a RESTful API

Tags: node.js, json, rest, restful-url

I am trying to make a basic RESTful API which works for the most part, but I would like to parse it url parameters such that I can apply multiple filters in one call

I have the following code:

```
app.get('/api/products/:id',(req, res) => {
  let sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id="+req.params.id;
  let query = conn.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results}));
  });
});
```

which I can use to apply one filter when I send a request like this:

`localhost/api/products/1`

but I would like to get all products with a name and their categories:

IE I would like to send a request like this:
`localhost/api/products?name=stier&category=hammer`
I would also like it to accept requests like this 
`localhost/api/products?category=hammer`

Is that possible and how can I adapt my code to do that.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Look into `req.query`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query parameters in Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43560557/query-parameters-in-express)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `query` parameters to that endpoint exactly as you mentioned. You can access those parameters using [req.query](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query)

for: `localhost/api/products?name=stier&category=hammer`, `req.query` will contain:

```
{
   name: 'stier',
   category: 'hammer'
}
```

For that URL, you'll have to add a route for: `/api/products` and leave `/api/products/:id` for fetching a single product.

Comment: with the path as '/api/products/:id', that url won't even enter to the callback function of (req,res)

Answer (score 0):

You need only to set '/api/products' the other part behind ? is called parameters and express puts them by itself on the object **req.query**

```
app.get('/api/products',(req, res) => {
    console.log(req.query)
    console.log(req.query.name)
    console.log(req.query.category)


})
```